# Is a charismatic build really worth it?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, fallout-3

I've built a highly intelligent, highly charasmatic but otherwise useless character in Fallout NW.

I'm about 1/4 through the main quest...at Novac, with a few dozen side quests, and I have yet to think 'gee, I'm sure glad I've put all those points into speech'.

I mean, other than convincing Good Spring citiziens in Ghost Town Gunfight to come to my aid, I have had not one chance to use my speech skills...

Does it come into its own more late game?

I'm thinking about playing FO3 as a charismatic character. Does it pay off in FO3 more? I can't remember...

Comment: I feel that between 35 and 50 speech is the sweet spot for more general builds. It allows you to pick up a good majority of interactions with npcs without losing too many points :)

Comment: Are you specifically interested in whether a high score in *Charisma* is worthwhile? Or are you more generally interested in the value if social skills like speech and barter?

Comment: I had more fun with a 10 str 10 end 10 luck and 0 in everything else build. Melee only with cannibal perk, ate everything I killed. So no, charisma isn't worth it if you're willing to kill and eat every human in the wasteland.

Answer (score 4):

A highly charismatic character is the fastest way to win in Fallout (This Speedrun highly relies on speech. SPOILERS in the video)

If you actually know what you are doing and play through the game for the nth time it is a good build. Although you have to adapt your play style a lot.

For an explorer or fighter it is a sub optimal build. This said an intelligent character is the only way to achieve the highest skill points in the game, making him viable in fights later on.

It depends on your difficulty settings if you have "a rough start" as an intelligent character or it is nearly impossible to pull it of without planing your routes like in the speedrun.

Comment: The embedded video hasn't loaded for some reason :/

Answer (score 1):

**Fallout: New Vegas**

Charisma in New Vegas modifies Barter, Speech and Companion Nerve. Companion Nerve gives each companion in the party +5% to their damage and armor, up to a maximum of +50% at 10 Charisma. --(its useless other than speech+CH checks) However, some interactions will not be available if your Charisma is too low.

**Fallout 3**

Modifies: Speech and Barter Skills, NPC Disposition

Charisma increases the disposition of all NPCs, which makes Speech checks easier. **Adding points to [speech] is almost always better than adding points to [charisma]**. Characters who do not use the Speech skill have little use for [charisma].

--Fallout Wiki, [Charisma](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Charisma)